# İnstagram video url not play HTML5 Player

Tags: html, instagram

I brought the video link from Instagram.

```
Video URL : https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/244392168_894608178139298_4686772010645637206_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=FcmD_8OecNwAX-7zfEc&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=615EB1F2&oh=1cb6287e70c30216eb9f9e4341f58a82&_nc_sid=83d603
```

Not playing in html5 player

```
<figure class="wp-block-video">
    <video
        src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t50.2886-16/244392168_894608178139298_4686772010645637206_n.mp4?_nc_ht=instagram.fist4-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=102&_nc_ohc=FcmD_8OecNwAX-7zfEc&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oe=615EB1F2&oh=1cb6287e70c30216eb9f9e4341f58a82&_nc_sid=83d603"
        controls="controls"
        width="600"
        height="400"
    ></video>
</figure>
```

Comment: looks like CORS problem.

Comment: how can i solve?

Answer (score 0):

This url is signed. So it will be available only for a limited amount of time. Only way to solve this problem, is to upload media to storage, to persist it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35146755)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).